# How do I keep my transaction from my CC to Bitcoin anonymous

Tags: exchanges, privacy, buy-bitcoins

I am trying to move some of my money from my Credit Card and turn it into Bitcoin. I just want to know if that transaction can be kept anonymous. Will my CC company receive and info of money being taken out. If they do will they know my location. IF so how can I keep it anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

Not likely, your bank will see whom the funds are sent to and the amount you are spending. After all they do need to send that money to the exchange that you are using to buy and sell on. Also many exchanges have to abide by know-your-customer and anti-money-laundering statutes that apply in the exchange's and your jurisdictions.  In the US buying from an individual with cash is the best way to anonimize your transaction.